# FFmpeg Android compilation: command not found

Tags: android, linux, ffmpeg, android-ndk

So I'm trying to build, on Ubuntu, FFmpeg from sources. Here's a script I assembled from here and there:

```
#!/bin/bash

NDK=$HOME/Desktop/adt/android-ndk-r19b
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-26/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64

function build_one
{
./configure
  --prefix=$PREFIX
  --arch=arm
  --target-os=linux
  --enable-cross-compile
  --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
  --sysroot=$SYSROOT
  --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS"
  --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS"
  $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG

  make clean
  make -j9
  make install
}

CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"

build_one
```

Unfortunately I get a list of following outputs:

```sh
ffbuild/config.sh is unchanged

./build_android_2.sh: line 26: --prefix=/home/maxest/Desktop/adt/android-ndk-r19b/sources/ffmpeg-4.1/android/arm: No such file or directory

./build_android_2.sh: line 27: --arch=arm: command not found

./build_android_2.sh: line 28: --target-os=linux: command not found

./build_android_2.sh: line 29: --enable-cross-compile: command not found

./build_android_2.sh: line 30: --cross-prefix=/home/maxest/Desktop/adt/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-: No such file or directory

./build_android_2.sh: line 31: --sysroot=/home/maxest/Desktop/adt/android-ndk-r19b/platforms/android-26/arch-arm/: No such file or directory

./build_android_2.sh: line 32: --extra-cflags=-Os -fpic -marm: command not found

./build_android_2.sh: line 34: --extra-ldflags=: command not found
```

I've double checked all the paths are correct. Although I create by hand folder `/home/maxest/Desktop/adt/android-ndk-r19b/sources/ffmpeg-4.1/android/arm` because there were no folder `android/arm`.

Comment: You need a backslash at the end of the line if you want to continue the command on the next line, i.e. `./configure \ ` followed by `--prefix=$PREFIX \ ` and so on. [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) autodetects [this issue](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2215)

Comment: You should have posted that as an answer ;). Although now I am getting "c compiler cannot create executables" :/